# Is it possible to delete message sent out by bot made from google script in slack channels?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack, slack-api

I have a google script that sends out messages from google script directly into slack. I have an issue whereby I cannot delete the messages sent into slack channels by the bot I made. Is it possible for us to delete the message sent out by such actions? I contacted slack support but not really helpful told me to look at https://api.slack.com/web or https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete

Is there any way where we as non-owner or admin for the slack server be able to create a delete action via the bot we coded from google script to allow a delete button for specific message sent out by the bot?

I'm using a webhook that sends into specific channels for my task and my codes ends with something like this below:

```
var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Comment: There must be a privileged and/or undocumented way to do this.  Messages that come from the SlackBot, like /remind items, have the Delete option in their More Actions dropdown.

Comment: @Ken_LYK Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: @CFD In the end, I just ask my administrator to delete them for me. Since then we migrated to a different method of doing the work.

Comment: @Ken_LYK I am currently facing this problem so I would love to get an update on how you were able to fix the issue.

When my bot sends a direct message to a user, the delete option isn't present when the user clicks the more actions dropdown.

I have installed some other slack apps and when these apps send messages, there is a delete option present in the message's more actions dropdown so I'm certain there's a way to enable it but then the docs aren't helping.

Answer (score 2):

With the `chat.delete` method you normally can delete your own messages. However, your bot will not be able to delete your messages, because they have been created via webhook. Those messages no longer belong to the bot user, but to the webhook app. (It might still work with the app's user token and assuming you are using a webhook from your own app, not via Slack's webhook app).

So the solution is to sent your messages via chat.postMessage, not webhook with the bot token. Then those messages belong to your bot user and your bot will be able to delete them.

There is one caveat though. Workspace admins can disable users from deleting their own messages (see [here](https://slack.com/intl/en-de/help/articles/115004868646-Manage-permissions-for-message-editing-and-deletion-)). In that scenario the only way to delete a message is to be an admin or owner.